Avoiding postback on a page refresh
I have a form which intakes data (a question to a Manager), and when the Manager has answered the question, the page will prompt the user that the question has been answered.  The user wants to keep the page open and be able to hit F5 to refresh the page, and do that until the prompt that says the question has been answered appears.
Every time the user hits F5, it re-submits the question.  I have code that clears out the form, and yet it continues to re-submit the question.  Here's that code:
protected void ResetAllControls(System.Web.UI.ControlCollection currentControls)
{
    foreach (Control c in currentControls)
    {
        string str = c.GetType().Name;

        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        else if (c.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)c;
            ddl.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        else
        {
            ResetAllControls(c.Controls);
        }
    }

    GridViewQuestionFiles.DataSource = null;
    GridViewQuestionFiles.DataBind();
}

Is there anything I can add here, or add to the Page_Load or something, that will stop the form from re-submitting the question when the page is refreshed?


and be able to hit F5 to refresh the page, and do that until the prompt that says the question has been answered appears.

I think that is very lame of a setup for users to have to refresh the page. I suggest you add a web method to the page, and have it run every 1 second. When the question is answered, your code can then refresh the page. Better yet, this setup will not "refresh" the page, and the browser will just "sit there" doing much of nothing from a user point of view, but will refresh when the database (I assume) shows the question having been answered.
You have some code to clear out the controls, but you don't say when/where/how you are running such code.
However, f5 is designed to re-submit and allow users to refresh a page when something goes wrong such as poor wi-fi.
This setup has been part of the web experience as to how a page re-submit works since internet dinosaurs roamed the earth. So, this is expected behavior.
However, what you can do is when the user hits submit button? Then in your code, simply add at the end of the submit code a redirect to the same page.
This means that the user gets a new fresh copy of the page, and thus hitting F5 will not re-submit the page, but only refresh.
So, then:
   ' My code here to do whatever the submit button does
   Response.Redirect("~/MyQuestionPage.aspx")

This of course will re-load the page, and the "question" text will of course clear out for you (like your clear out code). Of course, this means then you need some code to re-load the question text into the page. Hence, when you write out the question to the database, you need to save/get/persist the database question PK row ID.
Then on the first page load (do keep in mind that page load event will ALWAYS trigger before any button click).
Hence, you can't actually build a working web page and use page load event to setup controls and defaults unless you test/check if this is the "real" first page load. You do this by testing IsPostBack.
So, code to load up combo boxes GridViews or whatever? Such code can be placed in the page load event but is to only run on the REAL first page load by using IsPostBack flag that all pages have.
So, in page load event, you need to test/check say session(), and if yes, then you load the question back up.
So, logic then is:
    user enters question
    save to database - get PK id of that database row
    Session("MyQuestionID") = intQuestionPK
    Response.Redirect("MyQuestionPage.aspx")

Now, in page load event, you test/check if this is the first page load event with
 If Not IsPostBack Then
    if not IsNothing(Session("MyQuestionID") Then
       ' code here to pull the question from database
       ' code here to load up controls with the question fields/text
    End If
 End If

Above is air code.
As for refreshing? As noted, either add a web method to the page, or drop in a timer control inside of a update panel, and then the refresh can become automatic for you. Say, test/check every 1 or 2 seconds to check if the question been answered. And you might even consider placing the text + the eventual answer inside of that update panel.
This will allow a automatic page refresh, but only do so when the answer is finally completed.
So, either a update panel, or a JavaScript timer can be started here, and that client side timer event can call a web method, and if answer is completed, then the JavaScript code can click a hidden button, or even call __DoPostBack.
Using a update panel + timer control means you don't have to write any JavaScript.
The timer code behind can trigger a page re-load (again, simply using response.Redirect("to this current page.aspx).
So, while the page is "checking" for you, user's will not see a browser "spinner" or wait or page refresh each time your code behind runs to check/test the status of the question.
And bonus is that you eliminate all the troubles and woe's you having now by "encouraging" users to hit F5 (you REALLY don't want to have this idea as part of your software design and user experience). Having a design in which users are trained to hit F5 is going to bite you badly over time.
In other words, by adopting that update panel + timer control, you gain a far better user experience, and eliminate all the F5 issues.
And even if you adopt none of the above suggestions, keep in mind that you can "thwart" the F5 behavior by simply adding to the end of your existing submit button code a Response.Redirect("to this current page.aspx") page. In other words, simply navigate back to the current page in code behind, and now F5 will not do a re-submit of your page data. As noted, this does mean you have to (likely) use Session(), since in effect you are re-loading the page and starting fresh.
However, the first page load can check for Session(question pk id), and re-load that data anyway.
